# Polynomial as a sum of an exponent, -1 and another polynomial

Tags: polynomials

This is from the IMOmath website:

> Denote $P(x)=(1+x)(2+x)…(p−1+x)$. We know that $P(x)=x^{p-1}−1+pQ(x)$
>   fo-r some polynomial Q(x) with integer coefficients.
>   (p is prime)

How do we 'know this'? I cannot remember having seen it before.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch:

There are $p-1$ factors of $P(x)$, so when you multiply them out the terms you will get an expression of the forms:

$$P(x)=a_1x^{p-1}+a_2x^{p-2}+\cdots+a_{p-1}x+a_p.$$ 
And we want to show there is $Q(x)=b_{p-2}x^{p-2} + \cdots + b_1x +b_0$ such that $P(x)=x^{p-1}-1 + pQ(x)$.

The coefficient $a_1$ is $1$ since the only way to do get x^{p-1} is to choose only $x$ from each factor of $P(x)$.

Also, by Wilson's theorem we have that $(p-1)!$ congruent to $-1 \mod p$. So we can add a constant term in $Q(x)$ which will be divisible by $p$. Essentially, $a_p=(p-1)!$ so we can separate $a_p$ as $-1+p b_0$.

As for the remainder of terms of $Q(x)$, for the $x^{p-2}$ term, we have each of the terms from $1,2,\dots,p-1$ appearing with its additive inverse mod $p$ as coefficients. Since $p$ is odd (unless it is 2, in which case it is simple to see) there are an even number of terms and hence we can add them to get a number divisible by $p$. A similar idea can be used for other powers of $x$, but you will be able to show all the coefficients are divisible by $p$.

As I said this is just a sketch, but it should give you an idea of how to formalize the proof.